# Acronyms that include other acronyms

Tags: acronyms

I am using standard astrophysical acronyms that include other acronyms, e.g.
Coronal Mass Ejection (CME)
Interplanetary Coronal Mass Ejection (ICME)
and I would like them to work together, that is if I have already used \ac{CME} and the full version of CME has been printed I would like \ac{ICME} to result in Interplanetary CME (ICME), and if not it should give the full version.

In other words, I would like something like this

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}% Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{CME}{Coronal Mass Ejection}
\acro{ICME}{Interplanetary \ac{CME}}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}
\acresetall

The \ac{ICME} is a version of \ac{CME}.

\acresetall

A version of \ac{CME} is called \ac{ICME}.

\end{document}
```

to result in this
[image: What I want it to look like]

instead of this, which it does now
[image: What it actually looks like]

Comment: I used `acronym` for my thesis but in the final version (which is the only one I have here) got rid of most of my acronyms at the request of my internal examiner.  I'll have a look tonight because I'm sure I had some nested acronym and I'd have hated the "(CME) (ICME)" type of output you have here. I know it's written for `acro` but this question might help in conjunction with the `acronym` manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem. I added the macro `acx` which prints the long or the short version of the acronym and doesn't mark it as used.

**EDIT:** I changed my previous answer, because it was too complicated on second thought.

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}% Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acx}{\protect\@acx}%
\newcommand{\@acx}[1]{%
  \ifAC@dua
   \acl{#1}%
  \else
   \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
      \acs{#1}%
   \else
      \acl{#1}%
   \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{CME}{Coronal Mass Ejection}
\acro{ICME}{Interplanetary \acx{CME}}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}
\acresetall

The \ac{ICME} is a version of \ac{CME}.

\acresetall

A version of \ac{CME} is called \ac{ICME}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

My comment almost pointed in the right direction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{CME}{Coronal Mass Ejection}
    \acro{ICME}{Interplanetary \acl{CME}}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}
\acresetall

The \ac{ICME} is a version of \ac{CME}.

\acresetall

A version of \ac{CME} is called \ac{ICME}.

\end{document}
```

(note the use of `\acl{CME}` instead of `\ac{CME}` in the definition of `\acro{ICME}`) gives:

[image: Output of above code]

I thought you might have to play with whether or not acronyms are marked as used but apparently not in this case (`\aclu` etc.). Do check that the first expansion actually happens though, and/or do `\acresetall` at the start of the body (and of the abstract if you use them there).