# acronyms that include other acronyms (follow up)

Tags: acronyms

*I wanted to write a comment, but apparently you need 50 reputation for that. Sorry for the (almost) duplicate.*

I was happy to find my question has been asked and answered [on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247623/acronyms-that-include-other-acronyms/247648#247648). I was less happy to find out that I couldn't replicate the result.

I also have a follow up question: in my case there is a non-standard plural (my longer acro is high resolution computed tomography). How can something like this be modified to support that?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}% Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acx}{\protect\@acx}%
\newcommand{\@acx}[1]{%
  \ifAC@dua
   \acl{#1}%
  \else
   \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
      \acs{#1}%
   \else
      \acl{#1}%
   \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{CME}{Coronal Mass Ejection}
\acro{ICME}{Interplanetary \acx{CME}}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}
\acresetall

The \ac{ICME} is a version of \ac{CME}.

\acresetall

A version of \ac{CME} is called \ac{ICME}.

\end{document}
```

still resulted in the following output:

The Interplanetary Coronal Mass Ejection (ICME) is a version of Coronal Mass Ejection (CME). A version of Coronal Mass Ejection (CME) is called Interplanetary Coronal Mass Ejection (ICME)

I'm using ShareLaTeX, but I have the same result on TexMaker+MikTeX. Is there something I'm missing? How can I get the result I want?