# Acronyms that include other acronyms (acro package)

Tags: acronyms, acro

I am using some acronyms that include some other acronyms (e.g., MRI and structural MRI) (acro package). I would like the output to be:

*List of abbreviations*

*MRI magnetic resonance imaging*

*sMRI structural MRI*

and within the text:

*Magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) and structural MRI (sMRI); sMRI and MRI.*

Instead, I am getting something ugly:

[image]

As you can see, the 'MRI' acronym gets introduced in the List of abbreviations and therefore  is not defined at first usage in the text. I am aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247623/acronyms-that-include-other-acronyms), but the solution didn't work for me, probably because I am using a different package.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{mri}{
  short = MRI,
  long  = magnetic resonance imaging,
  tag   = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{smri}{
  short = sMRI,
  long  = structural \ac{mri},
  tag   = abbrev
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms[name=List of abbreviations]\markboth{List of abbreviations}{List of abbreviations}

\Ac{mri} and \ac{smri}; \ac{smri} and \ac{mri}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `list` key. Notice though that this might give unpleasant results if `smri` is used before the first time `mri` is used in the text.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{mri}{
  short = MRI,
  long  = magnetic resonance imaging,
  tag   = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{smri}{
  short = sMRI,
  long  = structural \ac{mri},
  list  = structural \acs*{mri},
  tag   = abbrev
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms[name=List of abbreviations]\markboth{List of abbreviations}{List of abbreviations}

\Ac{mri} and \ac{smri}; \ac{smri} and \ac{mri}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Was driving me crazy. :)